# SDN 4 return @QueryResult from custom Cypher query at run-time

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

In my SDN 4 project I have a pretty complex Cypher query that can't be defined at the compilation time via SDN repository @Query.

I need to build this query at run-time and as a result I need to get a custom SDN `@QueryResult` object.

Right now I can't find a way how to achieve this with a Spring Data Neo4j 4. Please help with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, this is not supported. `@QueryResult` only works on repository query methods. The next best thing to do is to use session.query to return a `org.neo4j.ogm.model.Result` and retrieve individual columns.

Tracking your issue here: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/issues/215